# How do I query one field from multiple search boxes that might be blank

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a field called "Expertise" which houses data about Doctors/Nurses/Surgeons such that Doctor1 may have "Pediatric surgeon; Neurology" in this field. Basically just a bunch of information about the Doctor will fill this field. I have four search boxes on a form where users can search for specific health care professionals. Someone may want to search for "pediatric", "Surgeon", and "neurology". I have this set up now using SQL and my code looks like this:

```
AND (dbo_Contact.Expertise) Like "*" & [Forms]![Data_Qry_Test_Page]![Expertise1] & "*" 
AND (dbo_Contact.Expertise) Like "*" & [Forms]![Data_Qry_Test_Page]![Expertise2] & "*" 
AND (dbo_Contact.Expertise) Like "*" & [Forms]![Data_Qry_Test_Page]![Expertise3] & "*" 
AND (dbo_Contact.Expertise) Like "*" & [Forms]![Data_Qry_Test_Page]![Expertise4] & "*"
```

Notice how I use Like because the user may want to look up the word "Surg" which will return records that contain surgery AND surgeon. This works great if a record has the words pediatric, surgeon, and neurology in their Expertise field. However I need this query to return Doctor1 who has only surgeon in his Expertise field AND Doctor2 who has neurology in his Expertise field.

If I use OR instead of AND it will return ALL RECORDS in the database. I believe I have to use the Nz() function but I'm not exactly sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Nz` to transform a Null text box value to a string which will never match any values stored in `dbo_Contact.Expertise`.  For example, say *"BOGUS"* will never match.  Then `Like '*BOGUS*'` will also never match.

So you can `OR` those `Nz` conditions together.  Any non-Null text boxes will select matching rows.  Null text boxes will not select any.  (And the query result set is the combination of rows selected by each of those conditions.)

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM dbo_Contact AS c
WHERE
   c.Expertise Like '*' & Nz(Forms!Data_Qry_Test_Page!Expertise1, 'BOGUS') & '*' 
OR c.Expertise Like '*' & Nz(Forms!Data_Qry_Test_Page!Expertise2, 'BOGUS') & '*' 
OR c.Expertise Like '*' & Nz(Forms!Data_Qry_Test_Page!Expertise3, 'BOGUS') & '*' 
OR c.Expertise Like '*' & Nz(Forms!Data_Qry_Test_Page!Expertise4, 'BOGUS') & '*'
```

Comment: Excellent point on the null fields.  I still think he has a boolean problem.  The fact that he has `AND` at the start of his constraints and says when he changes them to `OR` he gets the whole database makes me sure of that.  But it is not a complete answer without the Nz method.  +1 to you!

Comment: Yes, that `AND` at the beginning made me suspect there are other conditions we haven't seen.  But I didn't know what to do about that, so decided to give them a complete `WHERE` clause to adapt as needed.

Comment: I agree and you handled it well.  You deserve the answer check on this one. Where OP is a new user I wanted to make sure it was clear why he was getting the results he was.

Comment: I plan on checking both responses tomorrow morning thanks for your help.

Comment: This logic works great thanks HansUp! I had to tweak it a little since (like you both mentioned) there are more search criteria above and below Expertise. I added the OR NZ(xxxx, 'BOGUS') logic to all 19 of my search criteria. Quick question though, if the word 'BOGUS' somehow  were to pop up in the DB someday what would happen? Should I change 'BOGUS' to something more obscure like 'XXXYYYZZZ'?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, replace BOGUS with a string which you are sure will never match anything in `Expertise`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is just in the organization of your boolean logic.

The way your query works now, you would only get a result if `dbo_Contact.Expertise` exists in all 4 fields.

What you want however is if `Expertise` exists in field1 or field2 or field3 or field4.

The reason why you are getting the whole database currently is because you have a few criteria above this group that you've not included here.  Its saying "All this stuff above" OR "check this in expertise"

Instead you need to include it as one group anding it to the others above.

```
AND ((dbo_Contact.Expertise) Like "*" & [Forms]![Data_Qry_Test_Page]![Expertise1] & "*" 
     OR (dbo_Contact.Expertise) Like "*" & [Forms]![Data_Qry_Test_Page]![Expertise2] & "*" 
     OR (dbo_Contact.Expertise) Like "*" & [Forms]![Data_Qry_Test_Page]![Expertise3] & "*" 
     OR (dbo_Contact.Expertise) Like "*" & [Forms]![Data_Qry_Test_Page]![Expertise4] & "*")
```

Notice how I have put all the constraints in parens and "anded" them together with the previous constraints.

Comment: Thank you for the reply I will check this first thing tomorrow! Much appreciated.